# jquery's slow animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I've had enough with jquery's slowmolasse animation.

I'm not an expert, but however jQuery internals handles animation is too slow for me.

What alternatives do you suggest?

I've read: http://sixrevisions.com/javascript/10-impressive-javascript-animation-frameworks/

But it would be nice to know SO's opinions on the matter.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps there is something else amiss. With a properly supportive DOM/CSS, I don't find jQuery animation slow.

Answer (score 1):

So far i didn't see anything that's classified as "slow" while using jQuery and animate(). [Here's an example](http://www.crtaci.info/index.php?/topic/22815-nova-verzija-softvera-sreivanje/page__view__findpost__p__245738). Just click on "Back to top", which is on the left, below "Reputation":

[image]

Sometimes it's kinda quirky for me, but that's because I'm using FireFox with a lot of add-ons. Browsers like Safari and Chrome animate this without any glitches.

Answer (score 0):

Any library can be slow if you make it do too much. It doesn't even need to do animation. Anyway, I like Processing.js because I know some Processing.org and I don't have to relearn.

Comment: Yes but there's no doubt that jQuery's is ESPECIALLY slow.

Comment: @Jourkey - Based on what? Compared to what?

Comment: Come on, guys, doubtlessness needs no references. It's you who have to put some facts if you want to question doubtlessness.

Comment: I'm not sure how to write a performance tester for animations, and I'm not willing to spend time doing so. But looking at jquery's animations for things of sufficient complexity it looks to my eye less smooth than other animation frameworks like GX. Oh, and also codewise I can say, this is not as good of a way of doing animations than so on and so forth. But if your animations is not of sufficient complexity for you to tell a difference, well then good for you.

Comment: jQuery consistently ranks last though in overall performance for modern frameworks (discounting prototype) : http://dante.dojotoolkit.org/taskspeed/report/charts.html so what does that tell you about the quality of its code.

Comment: It tells me that there's lies, damned lies, and statistics (Disraeli).

Answer (score 0):

Use the Web worker (http://ejohn.org/blog/web-workers/) and the canvas tag, if needed, and do your own animation.  If you are just moving sprites it will be easy to do, though not every browser supports web workers. This would be the fastest javascript solution, I believe.